# mongod service restarts itself

Tags: mongodb, redhat

I have a three node mongodb cluster (with one arbiter) where every day around the same time, mongod service on the primary restarts itself without any apparent reason. I have the following entry in the logs:

```
2016-04-04T03:34:50.024-0500 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [conn42404] Count with ns: AutomationProd.Ingestion and query: { Source: "SMAC" } failed with exception: 11600 interrupted at shutdown code: 11600
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [conn42404] command AutomationProd.$cmd command: count { count: "Ingestion", query: { Source: "SMAC" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keyUpdates:0 numYields:83787 locks(micros) r:244348886 reslen:89 321535ms
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 11
2016-04-04T03:34:50.130-0500 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-04-04T03:34:50.137-0500 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-04-04T03:34:50.137-0500 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-04-04T03:34:50.137-0500 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2016-04-04T03:34:50.137-0500 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2016-04-04T03:34:50.137-0500 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
```

It looks like something is killing the service. There is nothing before the shutdown signal in the logs (just normal operation). Nothing weird in SAR logs (processor, memory, disk usage normal), no log messages in /var/log/messages.

It just looks like as if somebody restarted it manually but in fact nobody did, there is no indication of this in command history.

Mongodb version: 2.6.4-1
OS: RHEL 6.5

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the `got signal 15` message, so something is terminating it naturally.

What that thing is though is something you'll have to investigate.  Are there any other users on the box that could terminate the process?

Comment: Yes I know that it looks like something is terminating it but I cannot find out what. There is no other human user other than me but I've checked all users' command histories just in case. No indication of any restart. In fact nobody is logged in during the restart. Checked all crontabs for all users too.